# How reduce the vertical space between section and equation?

Tags: spacing

I use LaTeX to prepare a formula sheet for my upcoming exam. As a result, I want to fit as many formulas as possible on a page without damaging the readability too much.

I found several techniques for reducing the spacing in different parts of the document and I got this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[skip=1pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{left=0.45cm, right=0.45cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=1.5cm}

\setstretch{1}
\thickmuskip=6mu
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{2pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\blindtext
\begin{flalign*}
    x^2 + y^2 = 1 &&
\end{flalign*}
\section{Another example}
\begin{flalign*}
    e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0 &&
\end{flalign*}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

It works pretty well except for one issue I couldn't manage to figure out. If I have a section (or subsection or subsubsection) that is immediately followed by a displayed equation, there is a large vertical space between the section's title and the equation as you can see in the second paragraph of the example above. The vertical spacing between an equation and paragraph text is fine and the same goes for the spacing between a section and a paragraph text. Only when I have an equation after a section, it creates a larger space than I want.

How can I reduce the vertical spacing between a section and an equation? The current techniques presented in the example don't seem to cut it.

Comment: Try `\titlespacing*` instead of `\titlespacing`.

Comment: You  can also do `\noindent\begin{flalign*}` but since  using `parskip` it seems  that you do not want indent anything, then use  \titlespacing* is simpler and safer.